# SharingAllowedDomainList

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, external-users

We have a need to white list our SharePoint Online tenant to certain domains for external sharing. Luckily for us, there is the `SharingAllowedDomainList` property in the `Get/Set-SPOTenant`, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161390.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

The documentation states:

> Specifies a list of email domains that is allowed for sharing with the
>   external collaborators. Use the space character as the delimiter for
>   entering multiple values. For example, “contoso.com fabrikam.com”.

What is not clear, and cannot find any documentation on, is how to properly update this. If I have a list of domains already supplied, what happens when I need to add another programmatically? Is it simply a Set with this new domain and it will be appended or do I need to do a get first, append my domain to that variable, then set the domains with this?

Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to test this properly. I need to know what the behavior of the set command is if there are domains already listed. Is it an append or is it an overwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing it for the first time, you need to set another property called SharingDomainRestrictionMode to AllowList mode using below cmdlet:

```
Set-SPOTenant -SharingDomainRestrictionMode AllowList -SharingAllowedDomainList "amit.com"
```

Every time you update the SharingAllowedDomainList, it overwrites the existing values. So, you can use below cmdlet to update the domains:

```
$allowedDomains = Get-SPOTenant | select -ExpandProperty SharingAllowedDomainList
```

Now, if you want to add a domain, you can run:

```
$allowedDomains += " xyz.com"
```

If you want to remove a domain, you can run

```
$allowedDomains = $allowedDomains.Replace("domainToRemove.com","")
```

If you want to update an existing domain, you can run:

```
$allowedDomains = $allowedDomains.Replace("domainToUpdate.com","updatedDomain.com")
```

And finally, when you are done updating domains

```
Set-SPOTenant -SharingAllowedDomainList $allowedDomains
```